# Delaying LoginUI until custom shell is ready in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, interop, windows-8.1

I am writing a custom windows 8.1 shell, while it works fine, I am wondering if I could communicate with the login UI in a similar manner to how Windows Explorer does, ie delaying loginUI from disappearing until the shell completely finishes loading.

Edit1: I remember reading somewhere (a long time ago) that windows explorer sends something like "shell ready" message to the loginUI.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Please refine your question.

Comment: How quickly are you calling `RegisterShellWindow`?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/163451-windows-shell-programming/ ... It mentions sending (undocumented) message `0x400` to the desktop window to indicate that the shell is finished loading.

Comment: I intentionally called RegisterShellWindow after everything loads.

Comment: Maybe call it sooner so the system is aware of your window early on but wait until everything is loaded before showing it. It might be able to await visibility if it knows of it quickly. (Kind of guessing here.)

Comment: It seems 0x400 isn't applied anymore after WIndows XP (not surprising), but I found on that gamedev link a resource that I am sure has the answer in it somwhere https://www.freelists.org/archive/shell-coding, so my gratitude to you for linking such old site.